# How to clean up messy "Country" attribute from biopython pubmed extracts?

Tags: python, text, nlp, biopython

I have extracted ~60,000 PubMed abstracts into a data frame using [Biopython](https://biopython.org/). The attributes include "Authors", "Title", "Year", "Journal", "Country", and "Abstract". 
The attribute "Country" is very messy, with a mixture of countries, cities, names, addresses, free-text items (e.g., "freelance journalist with interest in Norwegian science"), faculties, etc.
I want to clean up the column only to contain the country - and "NA" for those records that are missing the entry, or have a free-text item that does not make sense.

Currently, my clean-up process of this column is very cumbersome:

```
pub = df['Country']
chicago = pub.str.contains('Chicago')
df['Country'] = np.where(chicago, 'USA', pub.str.replace('-', ' '))
au = pub.str.contains('@edu.au')
df['Country'] = np.where(au, 'Australia', pub.str.replace('-', ' '))
... and so on
```

Are you aware of some python libraries, or have some ideas for a more automated way of cleaning up this column?

Comment: You seem to be overwriting the result each time? Also why repeat the `pub.str.replace('-', ' ')` operation multiple times?

Comment: You can construct a mapping of `{thing_to_replace: thing_to_replace_with}`, then you could use `df['Country'].replace(replace_dict, regex=True)`.

Comment: Thanks - but since there are so many messy entries, and I would like to be able to fetch abstracts once a week I thought there would be some solution out there that are able to look through the country column and parse locations somehow.

Comment: Such silver bullets are hard to come by, you are better off reading in some country list CSV off of github (or wherever), then use `str.extract` to see if you can extract any country names from there. Another alternative is to install some package like geopy or w/e to parse addresses, but the success% there depends on how parsable your addresses are. That's upto you.

Comment: Okay, thanks - I will check that out